# Image does not convert to Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I am currently experiencing an issue where an image cannot be converted to Bitmap.

This is the code in question:

```
private void btnPicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog opFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            opFile.Title = "Choose a picture!";
            opFile.Filter = "jpg files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            if (Directory.Exists(appPath) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
            }

            if (opFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    Character.imageName = opFile.SafeFileName;
                    Stream stream = opFile.OpenFile(); //<------ This is the line in question
                    Bitmap toResize = new Bitmap(stream);

                    Image characterImage = ResizeImage(toResize, 200, 306);

                    imgCharacter.Image = characterImage;
                    characterImage.Save("Images/" + Character.imageName);
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please select a picture, exception code: " + exp.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                opFile.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Now basically this code works with every single image that I have tried, except 1. A single picture that my friends tried to upload will crash with the following error: Parameter is not valid.

What I have tried:

- First, the friend sent me the image in question. I downloaded it and faced the same problem.
- Then I had the friend send me other images that worked on his machine, these still worked.
- Next, I opened the image in question in Paint, "saved as" the picture to any folder, then it worked. In the process, I received a warning that saving the image this way may result in transparency loss.
- To check if transparency was the problem I had downloaded a "transparent" picture off the internet to check if that is the problem - the picture would load correctly.
- Lastly, I had searched for the exact same picture on the internet and tried to download it exactly the same way my friend did, I did not get the error.
- To make sure the image was not corrupted I asked the friend to download it once again and sent to me - the error would still occur.
- I ran the debugger line by line to pinpoint the exact line of code that crashes. I have no idea what could be the cause there.

Link to the image: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/413040202307731466/713873776143499294/babar1.jpg

I tried to find help online but could not find anything relevant so here I am, if there is anything particularly special to this picture (or a group of pictures) that I do not know about, please forgive, I am not a graphics designer in any way, shape or form.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you view JPG file in a window viewer?  You may have an old graphic card that doesn't support the JPG mode in the file.  There is an ASCII header in the jpg that can be seen if you open file in Notepad.   Check the graphic mode to see if you card works with the mode.

Comment: Yes, I can open this and any other image no problem. I opened the file with notepad but only found random characters like "þø/ßÿ–ïø" scattered across a few pages. I have no idea what graphic mode is but I did not change anything related to graphics as far as I remember. That should not matter anyway since my friend did have the same problem when his PC is much beefier than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the image you provided named "barbar1.jpg" in a hex editor and can see RIFF WEBPVP8 markers at the beginning. This means the image is not a JPG file it is a WEBP file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP

The error you are getting is when initializing the new Bitmap from a stream. Bitmap class only supports BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPG, PNG and TIFF.

Microsoft Paint supports WEBP which is why you are able to open it and view it. Microsoft and other image viewers ignore the file extension and parse the image based on the format of the file data itself. This is why you are able to rename the file to PNG, JPG, BMP, etc and it will still be readable by Paint.

Comment: I see, how does it happen that the image downloaded has a JPG format but in reality, the format is something absolutely different? Is there any way to prevent this by covering every "hidden" format in some way or will it be easier to simply reject such files completely? Can I silently convert a file to its default extension, (in this case JPG) or, if convert is a wrong word, ignore the hidden extension and use the default one? Sorry for all the questions but I am a little befuzzled by this.

Comment: I suspect the image was originally a .webp file and when someone downloaded it they saved it with .jpg filename. It's important to understand that the file name and extension can be renamed to anything you want, which means it should not be trusted. 

What matters most is the file data itself. For example a JPG file will always have FF D8 as the first two bytes of the file. A PNG file will always start with 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A. Converting an image file is a bigger task than just changing the file name. I would recommend using a library that handles more formats, or just fail elegantly.